# Appstore review submission w/ in-app purchase, pre "upgrade" or post "upgrade" test account?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am getting ready to submit an app with an in-app purchase (a one time, non-consumable upgrade to pro version).

When submitting for review, I need to provide a test account for my app as it requires authentication.

For the test account in question:
Do I provide a test account that is not yet upgraded to the pro version, or one that is already upgraded to the pro version?

Comment: Update: Success, app was accepted!

Per @SwitchKaas I provided auth credentials for an already upgraded account. In addition, I provided auth credentials for a standard account in the `Notes` section.

From what I can see in my activity log, the reviewer ignored the standard account I provided and went ahead to register a new standard account.

It took about 7 hours from the time I submitted app for review. The actual review itself is about 15 minutes (duration between emails with status of "In Review" to "Pending Developer Release").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. We have both situations, but in separate apps:

1. App with authentication, no IAP
2. Freemium app without authentication, and IAP (a one time, non-consumable upgrade to pro version). This app works as full version for the first X launches, before the pro features are disabled. So Apple Review can always test the full functionality, even without the IAP.

According to the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) they need to test the full functionality of the app. So then it's preferred to provide auth credentials for an upgraded version.

If they want/need to test your IAP unlock process, they might need a separate account that is not yet unlocked. To prevent any review delays by questions from Apple, you can provide these credentials upfront in App Store Connect in the `Notes` text field below the Sign-in text fields.

Please share your App Review experience afterwards.